# Why read_sas is converting strings to float?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, sas

I am trying to read a `.sas7bdat` file using `pandas` and I am having a hard time because `pandas` is converting strings values that look like a number into float.

For example, if I have a telephone number like `'348386789'` and I read it with the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_sas('test.sas7bdat', format='sas7bdat', encoding='utf-8')
```

The output would be `348386789.0`!

I can convert every single column with something like `df['number'].astype(int).astype(str)` but this would be very unefficent.

There is the same problem in the `read_csv` function but there you can use the argument `dtype` that sets the type for the required column (es. `dtype={'number': str)}`).

Is there a better way to read values in the desired format and use it in a dataframe?

**UPDATE**

I even tried `sas7bdat.py` and `pyreadstat` with the same results. You might say that the problem is in the data but using an online [tool](http://dumbmatter.com/sas7bdat/) to read sas7bdat the data seems correct.

Code for the other two libraries:

```
# pyreadstat module
import pyreadstat
df2, meta = pyreadstat.read_sas7bdat('test.sas7bdat')

# sas7bdat module
from sas7bdat import SAS7BDAT
reader = SAS7BDAT('test.sas7bdat') 
df_sas = reader.to_data_frame()
```

If you want to try, (and you have a SAS license), you can create a `.sas7bdat` file with the following content:

```
column_1,column_2,column_3
11,20190129,5434
19,20190228,5236
59,20190328,10448
76,20190129,5434
```

Answer (score 2):

Use sas7bdat.py instead. That typically preserves the dataset formats better.

IF a particular column is defined as character in the SAS dataset, then sas7bdat will read it as as string regardless of how the contents look like. As a lazy example, I created this dataset in SAS:

```
data test;
  id = '1111111'; val = 1; output;
  id = '2222222'; val = 2; output;
run;
```

And then ran the following Python code on it:

```
reader = SAS7BDAT('test.sas7bdat')
df = reader.to_data_frame()
print(df)

cols = reader.columns
for col in cols:
    print(str(col.name) + " " + str(col.type))
```

Here is what I see:

```
        id  val
0  1111111  1.0
1  2222222  2.0

b'id' string
b'val' number
```

If you are looking to 'intelligently' convert numbers to strings based on context, then you may need to look elsewhere. Any SAS dataset reader is just going to read based on the format specified within the dataset at best.

Comment: I think your analysis is partially correct because not every reader is reading my data as numbers. This one for example: https://github.com/dumbmatter/sas7bdat-web-viewer is reading it correctly. Unfortunately is written in javascript tho. I think the problem resides in pandas and it happens even reading csvs with the difference that in read_csv you have the option of specifying the data type for each column.